# How to kill all glassfish instances

Tags: java, mysql, process, glassfish, kill

Can anyone tell me how to kill a Glassfish instance using the port 4848 and 8080.

I installed Glassfish, and found that the Glassfish installation isn't working properly, so deleted all the Glassfish files from my ubuntu machine with stopping the Glassfish server (./asadmin stop-domain).

Now I downloaded other Glassfish version (nightly build 5.0, because JDBC MySQL doesn't work) and tried to start the server (./asadmin start-domain). I get the following error.

> There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is
>   another instance of a GlassFish server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me how to kill a Glassfish instance using the port
>   4848 and 8080.

There is probably running only one instance of Glassfish on this ports, but you can kill it like this:

```
pkill -f glassfish
```

If you don't have a root shell you might have to use `sudo` in front of the cmd.